# Best books to learn distributed systems/computing?

Tags: self-learning

I work in distributed systems and I need to learn the general architecture of it.

Here's the general level roadmap that I want to follow.

- Go via distributed system/computing textbooks.
- Read system design books/do system design courses.

I am only asking for distributed system/computing textbooks in this QNA.

What I don't want:

- Designing data intensive applications by Martin Kleppman.

What I want?

- Books like Distributed Operating Systems: Concepts and Design PK Sinha
- Distributed Systems: Concepts & Design by Colouris
- Mukesh Singhal Distributed Computing

I don't prefer Tanenbaum simply because he's not my type of writer.

Do you've anything else on your mind?

For courses:

I'll take system design courses from one website, be it udemy, youtube or anywhere else.

The courses on distributed systems are sold as "software architecture" "system design" :D And I'm going to search for them.